# Add hidden UIView to UITableView similar to UIRefreshControl

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, uirefreshcontrol

Very similar to a UIRefreshControl, I'm trying to put a UIView on top of a UITableView. Dragging down the table view should reveal the view and have it stay there. Dragging up should hide it again and then scroll the table view. When hidden the table view should scroll normally. Scrolling back to the top should either reveal the hidden view again, or snap to the hidden state. Ultimately the revealed view should contain some buttons or a segmented control. It should look and behave very similar to the OmniFocus App.

Hidden View in [OmniFocus](https://itunes.apple.com/ch/app/omnifocus-2-for-iphone/id690305341?l=en&mt=8&at=10lMuD)
[image: Hidden View in OmniFocus]

Revealed View in [OmniFocus](https://itunes.apple.com/ch/app/omnifocus-2-for-iphone/id690305341?l=en&mt=8&at=10lMuD)
[image: Revealed View in OmniFocus]

This is how far I got. Especially the snapping back to the hidden state when the table view scrolls back up does not work. If you time it right you'll end up stuck in the middle of top view, which is exactly not what I want.

```
static CGFloat const kTopViewHeight = 40;

@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, weak) UIView *topView;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat dragStartY;
@end

@implementation ViewController

#pragma mark - View Lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    CGRect topViewFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, -kTopViewHeight, 320, kTopViewHeight);

    UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:topViewFrame];
    myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor]; // DEBUG
    self.topView = myView;
    [self.tableView addSubview:myView];
}

#pragma mark - UIScrollViewDelegate

- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    NSLog(@"scrollViewWillBeginDragging %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(scrollView.contentOffset));
    self.dragStartY = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    NSLog(@"scrollViewDidScroll %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(scrollView.contentOffset));
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0) {
        // reset the inset
        scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    } else if (scrollView.contentOffset.y >= -kTopViewHeight) {
        // set the inset for the section headers
        scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-scrollView.contentOffset.y, 0, 0, 0);
    } else if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < -kTopViewHeight) {
        // don't scroll further when the topView's height is reached
        scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-kTopViewHeight, 0, 0, 0);
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, -kTopViewHeight);
    }
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
    NSLog(@"scrollViewDidEndDragging %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(scrollView.contentOffset));
    CGFloat yOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;

    if (yOffset < 0) {
        BOOL dragDown = self.dragStartY > yOffset;
        CGFloat dragThreshold = 10;

        if (dragDown) {
            if (yOffset <= -dragThreshold) {
                [self snapDown:YES scrollView:scrollView];
            } else {
                [self snapDown:NO scrollView:scrollView];
            }
        } else if (!dragDown) {
            if (yOffset >= dragThreshold - kTopViewHeight) {
                [self snapDown:NO scrollView:scrollView];
            } else {
                [self snapDown:YES scrollView:scrollView];
            }
        }
    }
}

- (void)snapDown:(BOOL)down scrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction|UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut|UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^{
                         if (down) {
                             // snap down
                             scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, -kTopViewHeight);
                             scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(kTopViewHeight, 0, 0, 0);
                         } else {
                             // snap up
                             scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);
                             scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
                         }
                     }
                     completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
//paging for data you can use this spinner

    spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
        [spinner stopAnimating];
        spinner.hidesWhenStopped = NO;
        spinner.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44);
        tblView.tableFooterView = spinner;
        tblView.tableFooterView.hidden = YES;

#pragma mark Table pull to refresh data....

    - (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView
                      willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate{

        CGPoint offset = aScrollView.contentOffset;
        CGRect bounds = aScrollView.bounds;
        CGSize size = aScrollView.contentSize;
        UIEdgeInsets inset = aScrollView.contentInset;
        float y = offset.y + bounds.size.height - inset.bottom;
        float h = size.height;

        float reload_distance = 50;
        if(y > h + reload_distance && _nextPage) {
            NSLog(@"load more data");
            tblView.tableFooterView.hidden = NO;
// index for new page of data will increment here
            index = index + 1;
            [spinner startAnimating];
            [self performSelector:@selector(requestData) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0f];
        }
    }

   // when you request for data and wants to stop spinner 

     CGPoint offset = tblView.contentOffset;
    //    if new page is there set bool 
          _nextPage = YES;
    //    want to remove spinner
          tblView.tableFooterView.hidden = YES;
          [spinner stopAnimating];
          [tblView setContentOffset:offset animated:NO];
```

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear, but I'm NOT looking to replace UIRefreshControl nor do I need any refresh functionality. It should just be a static view with a UISegmentedControl that looks LIKE a UIRefreshControl in terms that it sits on top of the UITableView and gets revealed when panning down.